# Qualcuno conosce un sito o qualche eserciziario dove allenarsi con la punteggiatura?

Tags: resources, punctuation

Ho bisogno di allenarmi per risolvere dubbi sui periodi lunghi.

Comment: ***La punteggiatura*** http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/it/lingua-italiana/consulenza-linguistica/domande-risposte/punteggiatura

Comment: Esercizi di punteggiatura- https://grammatica-italiana.dossier.net/punteggiatura/index.html

Comment: @Gio La casella per le risposte è più in basso :).

Comment: Benvenuto/a su Italian.SE!

Comment: @Gio: Sono d'accordo con Denis: potresti scriverlo come risposta?

Comment: @Charo - sono soltanto dei link a dei siti,  non sono una vera risposta sull’uso della punteggiatura. Inoltre non sono sicuro che la richiesta di “reference” sia on-topic. Su ELU ad esempio  non lo è e questo tipo di domande vengono trasferite su Meta.

Comment: È un vero peccato che domande con richieste di fonti di questo genere siano "off-topic". Se ne potrebbe discutere su Meta (sulla validità o meno di tali domande)? O quest'ultime sono già nella prassi "on-topic" su Meta?

Comment: Il problema è che i siti SE privilegiano domande che ammettono una risposta, se non unica, ben precisa, mentre qui si chiedono suggerimenti su un certo argomento. È come se nel SE sul cinema si chiedessero consigli su film di guerra: lì una domanda del genere sopravvivrebbe tre secondi. Qui non so se abbiamo criteri specifici in merito, ma forse un'idea può essere di chiudere questa domanda e aggiungere una sezione sulla punteggiatura alla nostra [domanda “meta” sulle risorse](https://italian.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122/what-good-reference-works-on-italian-are-available-online).

Comment: @Easymode44: Se n'è discusso [qui](https://italian.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1249).